# How do I move 1 object in an array to another array in javascript and then show both in a listview ( jquery )

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html, listview

So for a school assignment I need to write a basic mobile web application, using jquery and javascript. I need to make a page where you can add a title and author of a book and add it to a list using local storage. So far so good but I want to make 2 lists, one for books to read and one for read books. Now I made the listview with a split icon so when it's clicked that book should move to the other list. That listview contains also a split icon which should remove the book in it's whole.

The adding part is working and the added books are displayed in the listview but I can't seem to get the button working to change the list the book is in. Please help me I'm loosing my mind. Here is my html and javascript code:

```
<!-- OVERVIEW -->
    <section id="overview" data-role="page" data-theme="b">
        <!-- CONTENT -->
        <div class="ui-content">
            <div>
                <a href="#add" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Add a new book</a>
                <h1>Books to read</h1>
        </div>
            <ul id="booksToRead" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="check" data-theme="b" data-split-theme="b" data-inset="true"></ul>

            <h1>Read books</h1>
            <ul id="readBooks" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="delete" data-theme="b" data-split-theme="b" data-inset="true"></ul>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And the javascript code

```
function add() {
    // Retrieve the entered form data
    var title = $('[name="bookTitle"]').val();
    var author = $('[name="bookAuthor"]').val();

    var book = {title:title, author:author};

    // Fetch the existing books to read
    var booksToRead = getObjects("booksToRead");

    // Push the new item into the existing list
    booksToRead.push(book);

    // Store the new list
    saveObjects(booksToRead, "booksToRead");

    //reset textfields
    $('[name="bookTitle"]').val('');
    $('[name="bookAuthor"]').val('');

    // Load the page with all the books
    window.location.href = "#overview";

}

function getObjects(name) {
    // See if objects are inside localStorage
    if (localStorage.getItem(name)) {
        // If yes, then load the objects
        var objects = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name));
    } else {
        // Make a new array of objects
        var objects = new Array();
    }
    return objects;
}

function saveObjects(objects, name) {

    // Save the list into localStorage
    localStorage.setItem(name, JSON.stringify(objects));
}

function read(dit){
    var readBooks = getObjects("readBooks");
    var booksToRead = getObjects("booksToRead");
    var book = booksToRead[dit];

    // Push the new item into the existing list
    readBooks.push(book);

    // Store the new list
    saveObjects(readBooks, "readBooks");

    //Delete from the old list
    deleteme(dit, "booksToRead");

    //Reload page
    window.location.reload();
}

function deleteme(dit, listName) {
    // Fetch existing objects
    var objects = getObjects(listName);

    // Delete given object from list
    objects.splice(dit, 1);

    // Save list
    saveObjects(objects, listName);

    //Reload page
    window.location.reload();
}

function loadPage() {
    // Fetch the existing objects
    var booksToRead = getObjects("booksToRead");
    var readBooks = getObjects("readBooks");

    // Clear the lists
    $('#booksToRead').find('li').remove();
    $('#readBooks').find('li').remove();

    // Add every object to the objects list
    $.each(booksToRead, function(index, item) {
        var title = item.title;
        var author = item.author;
        $('#booksToRead').append('<li><a>' + title + ' - ' + author + '</a><a         class="read" onclick="read(' + booksToRead.index + ')" data-transition="none"></a></li>');
    });
    $.each(readBooks, function(index, item) {
        var title = item.title;
        var author = item.author;
        var listName ="readBooks";
        $('#readBooks').append('<li><a>' + title + ' - ' + author + '</a><a class="delete" onclick="delete(' + readBooks.index + ', ' + listName + ')" data-transition="none"></a></li>');
    });

    $('#booksToRead').listview();
    $('#booksToRead').listview("refresh");
    $('#readBooks').listview();
    $('#readBooks').listview("refresh");
}

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#overview', function(event) {
    loadPage();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've think i got your error, in your $.each loop try removing your

```
booksToRead.index
// and
readBooks.index
```

for just

```
index
```

So, your $.each loops will look like that:

```
 $.each(booksToRead, function(index, item) {
   var title = item.title;
   var author = item.author;
   $('#booksToRead').append('<li><a>' + title + ' - ' + author + '</a><a  class="read" onclick="read(' + index + ')" data-transition="none">ddddd</a></li>');
 });
 $.each(readBooks, function(index, item) {
    var title = item.title;
    var author = item.author;
    var listName ="readBooks";
    $('#readBooks').append('<li><a>' + title + ' - ' + author + '</a><a class="delete" onclick="delete(' + index + ', ' + listName + ')" data-transition="none"></a></li>');
 });
```

Your are trying to get the property "index" of the object booksToRead while what you need to do is get the index param property of the $.each loop function, so you will get the correct index of the book you want to move.
You don't get error in the console because booksToRead.index === undefined and don't generates any exception, so, your index become ..."onclick="read(undefined)"...
Hope i've helped, good luck with your project!

Comment: Omg that's it! Thank you so much. Don't know how that slipped by haha